# Unable to instantiate application "com.company.application" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.application"

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, dagger

I was trying to build an application that uses Dagger Hilt following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0of23TxIKc&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCTimTCpEL5FZgaWdIZQuB7m).
I was checking whether the app is working after setting up a list of objects from API but then I kept getting a following error:

```html
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.pokedex_tutorial.PokedexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.pokedex_tutorial.PokedexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~dm2RLkrZitO-2YAba3pu3A==/com.example.pokedex_tutorial-4k4KLyudFgSUrCU--HNRXA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~dm2RLkrZitO-2YAba3pu3A==/com.example.pokedex_tutorial-4k4KLyudFgSUrCU--HNRXA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1244)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6683)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.pokedex_tutorial.PokedexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~dm2RLkrZitO-2YAba3pu3A==/com.example.pokedex_tutorial-4k4KLyudFgSUrCU--HNRXA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~dm2RLkrZitO-2YAba3pu3A==/com.example.pokedex_tutorial-4k4KLyudFgSUrCU--HNRXA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:51)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1158)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1236)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6683) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
                                                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/pokedex_tutorial/Hilt_PokedexApplication;
                                                                                                            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                                                                                                            ... 14 more
                                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.pokedex_tutorial.Hilt_PokedexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~dm2RLkrZitO-2YAba3pu3A==/com.example.pokedex_tutorial-4k4KLyudFgSUrCU--HNRXA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~dm2RLkrZitO-2YAba3pu3A==/com.example.pokedex_tutorial-4k4KLyudFgSUrCU--HNRXA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
                                                                                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                            ... 17 more
```

I couldn't find any solution that works for me so all help is deeply appreciated.
If it helps the source code is on [my repository](https://github.com/baqterya/pokedex_tutorial)

I've seen that for some people the problem stemmed from gradle files so here they are:

```html
// project level gradle
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44.2" apply false
}
```

```html
// build level gradle

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.pokedex_tutorial"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.pokedex_tutorial"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")


    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0-alpha02")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.1.0-alpha12")

    // Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0")

    // Timber
    implementation("com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1")

    // Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1")

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")

    // Coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.1.1")
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.7.0")

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.44.2")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.44.2")

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44.2")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")
    ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0-alpha01")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44.2")


    implementation("androidx.palette:palette-ktx:1.0.0")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on a similar problem: the issue was that ksp is still not supporting hilt properly. I fixed the issue by reverting back to kapt